# UIImageview animation and UILabel inside UICollectionview disappearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I'm having problems with an animation inside the UICollectionview cell. When I touch my animation, it disappear. I have a refresh time of 8 seconds and when this time is reached, the animation back to normal. My labels inside the cells are having the same issue. It's weird this behavior because when I use static images, they don't disappear.

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Arrived while looking for the answer to this. Faced similar issue. Image animation would stop when clicked on the collectionViewCell.

Not sure what the bug is, but one solution that worked for me, was to disable selection on the CollectionView.
In case, you do not need selection on the collection view, just set allowsSelection to NO for the collection view and the bug will go away.